# embedding fonts Fonte_Nexa-TTF and Fonte_Nexa in css

Tags: css, fonts, font-face, http-status-code-403, font-family

I am working on a website on which I want to apply the following fonts:

**1.** Fonte_Nexa-TTF 
 
**2.** Fonte_Nexa

I have placed the above fonts in the **css/fonts** folder as shown below in an image:

[image]

Inside **Fonte_Nexa-TTF** directory, I have the following fonts:

[image]

In the CSS, I have placed the following codes on the top but it doesn't seem to work.

```
@font-face {
font-family:"Fonte Nexea";
src: 
url("fonts/Fonte_Nexa-TTF") format("truetype"),
url("fonts/Fonte_Nexa") format("opentype");
}
```

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what changes I need to make in the CSS codes above so that it start working. Also, at console I am getting the following error:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your references are for directories instead of the fonts themselves. Try adding the file names for the specific font file within the directory and see if that makes a difference.

```
@font-face {
font-family:"Fonte Nexea";
src: 
url("fonts/Fonte_Nexa-TTF/fontname.ttf") format("truetype"),
url("fonts/Fonte_Nexa/fontname.otf") format("opentype");
}
```

Comment: I have updated my question. Let me know it helps. I have placed an image for  `Fonte_Nexa-TTF` directory.

Comment: There are tonnes of fonts inside Fonte_Nexa-TTF directory. I am wondering which one I should go with.

Comment: I would start with the Nexa.ttf one, but it really just depends on which one you want to use. Those should all be different variations on the same font.